# Is it possible to write programs for other OSs in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, mac, ide

Is there an Integrated Developemnt Environment (IDE) that enables us to write programs for Windows and Mac in Ubuntu?

Comment: You could use virtualbox to virtualize any environment you want.  What language are you developing in?

Comment: C++ or C#. but if there is a language similar to Visual Basic, I'd prefer that.

Comment: You'll be happy to know that [Mono](http://askubuntu.com/a/143164/22949) actually [supports Visual Basic 8.](http://www.mono-project.com/VisualBasic.NET_support)

Comment: As long as you just write it for the specific OS (so don't import libraries and the like based on other OSs), you should be fine. So yes.

Comment: Do you mean so long as the program is *not* OS-specific, then it should run on multiple OSes? It's not totally clear what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://monodevelop.com/

> MonoDevelop is an IDE primarily designed for C# and other .NET
>   languages. MonoDevelop enables developers to quickly write desktop and
>   ASP.NET Web applications on Linux, Windows and Mac OSX. MonoDevelop
>   makes it easy for developers to port .NET applications created with
>   Visual Studio to Linux and to maintain a single code base for all
>   platforms.

MonoDevelop is based on [Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page), a free open source implementation of the .NET Framework. Mono supports C#, but also [supports Visual Basic 8](http://www.mono-project.com/VisualBasic.NET_support). MonoDevelop supports multiple languages, including C# and Visual Basic, So if you prefer to develop in VB, you can do that with MonoDevelop on Ubuntu, and you can run your VB programs on Ubuntu (and Windows) too.

Sounds like that is what you need.

Comment: @EliahKagan, please do not edit new content in the actual answer, but feel free to add it in a comment (or write your own answer)

Comment: On AskUbuntu, [editing answers like this is considered good](http://askubuntu.com/faq#editing). However, respecting the intent of the original author is at least as important. I have improved my edit (it was lacking, originally). But if you still prefer your original version, **please feel free to revert the edit**. You can revert an edit in the [revisions list](http://askubuntu.com/posts/143164/revisions), by using the `rollback` link.

Comment: I don't mind having corrective edits for spelling errors and grammar, but I personally think that major edits should be reserved the original author based on suggestions put in comments.  This is based on my experience elsewhere on SE.

Comment: Corrective edits for major content, and additive edits in the spirit of and contextually appropriate to the original post, tend to be welcome on AskUbuntu. Even edits deleting material as it becomes less useful for future releases occur with some regularity. I would imagine that different SE sites have different community standards about what kinds of edits are appropriate--in AskUbuntu, we tend to think that edits that *improve* the post are good, so long as they don't disrespect or misrepresent any of the authors. I have edited and been edited in this way many times here, without complaints.

Comment: Adding new content is ok and is encouraged on Ask Ubuntu.  Its all about improving Questions and Answers - adding good new content and removing old irrelevant content.  If in doubt please raise a Meta question.  Thanks.

Comment: As I said I do not mind edits, but I'd like the big ones to be written by myself, and I'd like at least a _chance_ to be able to do the editing it in my own words before timing out and others doing it.  Apparently that is not customary on this SE site.  Duly noted.

Answer (score 4):

You can cross-compile Windows executables under Ubuntu using the `mingw32` package, as described in the answers to this question:

[How to program for Windows in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14442/how-to-program-for-windows-in-ubuntu)

Alternatively, if you stick to platform independent APIs (e.g. GTK or Qt for graphical applications, or any other libraries that are portable to the target system) it is possible to port to Windows or MacOS without too much trouble.

In either case, you will probably want to test them on your chosen target platform to make sure they actually function correctly there.  So it won't necessarily remove the need to access those platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Qt Creator is one such IDE:

http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/qt-creator/

Answer (score 1):

No one has said [java](http://jdk-distros.java.net/ubuntu.html) !

And the most popular ide [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

[Java for apple.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/00-Intro/JavaDevelopment.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should definiely consider Java or Python, both languages are platform-independent and are relatively easy to program. But the advantage with python is that you do not have to compile it so that it does not have to be compiled in Windows to run on it.