# How to publish a Quickly-generated program to Windows?

Tags: application-development, quickly

Please advise the best way to publish a Quickly-generated program to Windows.

Comment: I also need an answer , But this question appears to be offtopic

Comment: While I think this question would benefit from more details, I don't think it's off-topic. We haven't closed questions about how to develop [*programs intended specifically for Windows*](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143162/is-it-possible-to-write-programs-for-other-oss-in-ubuntu) on Ubuntu. Quickly is an Ubuntu utility. Development *on* (not just for) Ubuntu, and how to use programs in Ubuntu, are [on-topic for this site](http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions).

Comment: Let me clarify:  I am convinced about Linux and Ubuntu, and I am changing my "computer life" to them rather than MS Windows.  But some programs I develop for Ubuntu I would also like to provide to MS Windows users.  Quickly uses Python, which I gather can be run on MS Windows, but I'm wondering about the easiest way to get a Quickly-designed program made into a MS Windows .exe.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a Windows pc to build it on. On this Windows pc you will want to install python, gtk, pygobject, pycairo, pygtk, py2exe, and SetupTools. Also you will need any other dependency/module your app might need but SetupTools should make that easier to pull off. Also you will need to remove anything in your application that would not be available to Windows. (i.e. Unity Bindings). Then you would run your app through Py2Exe and install it. Its not going to be a cake walk but its possibly possible :) Good Luck and Godspeed

Further reading/sources:

- [PyGTK FAQ article on this](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?file=faq21.005.htp&req=show)
- [Write-up by Sebastian Noack on the subject](http://www.no-ack.org/2010/09/complete-guide-to-py2exe-for-pygtk.html)
- Python for Windows: www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.3/
- GTK for Windows: www.gtk.org/download/index.php
- PyGobject for Windows: ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygobject/
- PyCairo for Windows: ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pycairo/
- PyGtk for Windows: ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/
- Py2EXE: www.py2exe.org/
- SetupTools: pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#downloads